# onclick trigger doesn't work first click

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm confused why the onclick function doesn't register the first time it is clicked. Each div with the onclick trigger has to be clicked twice the first time.

```js
function selected(elmnt) {
  if (elmnt.style.backgroundColor == "transparent")
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "#990000"
  else
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
}
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onclick="selected(this)">click me</div>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try outputting `elmnt.style.backgroundColor` when you click on it.

Comment: @j08691 That would be `""`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because your element style is not transparent. Only your element's `computedStyle` is. Try this:

```js
function selected(elmnt) {
  if (elmnt.style.backgroundColor == "transparent")
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "#990000"
  else
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
}
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onclick="selected(this)" style="background-color: transparent;">click me</div>
```

There's also the natural way:

```js
function selected(elmnt) {
  if (elmnt.style.backgroundColor == "")
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "#990000"
  else
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = ""
}
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onclick="selected(this)">click me</div>
```

Comment: Ah! Brilliant catch! :)

Comment: This is correct, but he doesn't need to assign an inline style. That just creates more maintenance. Instead change the `if` condition to look for an empty string and set the style to an empty string to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The element doesn't start with a background-color of transparent so it always goes to the else. Changing the div to

```
<div id="container" onclick="selected(this)" style='background-color:transparent'>www</div>
```

will make it work. A css style sheet doesnt' append style to the DOM elements physically.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above absolutely agree initially style is not set.

Just to tell you for next time how to DEBUG it
us console.log()  click F12 for developer tools then console tab

I am fan of short IFs when simple IF

```
 <script>
    function selected(elmnt) {
        console.log(elmnt.style.backgroundColor)
        var bG= elmnt.style.backgroundColor
        elmnt.style.backgroundColor = ( bG == '' || bG == "transparent") ? "#990000" : "transparent";
    }      
</script>
```